# Is there a mathematical function for a sinusoidal function that each wave is omega shaped?

Tags: functions, trigonometry

I am interested to know if there is any possibility to define the function or equation for a sinusoidal function , similar to **`|sine(x)|`** but with each wave as an Omega shape , as you can see in the image, there is a continuous variation from S shaped Omega to C shaped, so it seems to me that there can be a function that could also consider this.

clearly it would be something like a system of equations :

x=x(t)
y=y(t)

later I would need to draw these functions  in 2D space, so knowing that the shape of S shaped omega is in contrast with the definition of a function ( no more than one point should be cut along each vertical line cutting the function)
but I hope I would be able to do this through the definition of some cloud of points in a programming software

[image: Examples of shapes]

Comment: for an unknown reason, I am not able to insert the 9KB png image, could anyone help ?

Comment: Do you know how to plot parametric curves (where the $x$ and $y$ coordinates are given by functions of, say, $t$)?

Comment: I have not done it up to this moment. I hope there's a method

Comment: @Blue if you know the parametric formula, please let me know, I'll try to see how I can draw it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A series of circular arcs will give you a family that includes the "S"- and "C"-shaped curves. ("U" doesn't fit the pattern, so I'll ignore it here.)

Specifically, consider these arcs of measure $2\alpha$ (in radians), with a fixed opening of $2a$ at the "bottom" or "top". The radius of the arcs is $a\csc\alpha$, and the displacement of their centers from the horizontal is $-a\cot\alpha$.

[image]

Parameterizing with $t$, define
$$k := \left\lfloor \frac{t+1}{2} \right\rfloor$$
(that is, the ["floor"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions) of $\frac12(t+1)$).
This tells us which arc we're trying to draw. The arc will have center $(x_k,y_k) := (2 ak, (-1)^{k + 1} a \cot\alpha)$ and radius $r := a\csc\alpha$; our parameterization will look like
$$\begin{cases}
x(t) = x_k + \phantom{(-1)^k} r \sin(t - 2 k)\alpha\; \\
y(t) = y_k + (-1)^k\,r\cos(t-2 k)\alpha
\end{cases}$$

Here are a few variations, for $\alpha$ at (the radian equivalent of) $30^\circ$, $45^\circ$, $60^\circ$, $90^\circ$ (the "C" curve), $120^\circ$, $135^\circ$, $150^\circ$ (the threshold when neighboring arcs touch), and $160^\circ$.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for the Amazing response, for an unknow reason I don't see the attached images, is it the same for you? Why doesnt the U shape work? I feel the U shape is already a sinusoidal function. Seems the point of instability

Comment: @FabioSpaghetti: I don't have a problem seeing the images. I'm not sure what the problem could be.

Comment: @FabioSpaghetti: The "U" shape has vertical segments, so, like a vertical line, it's not a function. It's certainly possible to parameterize a U-shaped path, and more generally a path with straight segments joining the successive arcs, but it's a little more complicated than the arc-to-arc paths given above: the arc-parts and the segment-parts require separate "piece-wise" parameterizations. I'll have to come back to this later. ... You should un-accept this answer in the meantime, so as not to discourage others from making their own attempts.

Comment: Thank you very much. It's very encouraging that you'll think more about this problem. May I generalize the problem a bit? There's also a possibility that the upper arcs have one radius and the lower ones another. Is it possible to include in the function? In geometrical definition, the parametrization includes the wave Amplitude, wave pitch that define the flank angle

Comment: @FabioSpaghetti: (Almost-)Anything is possible. :)  (In the above, to force a particular radius, $r$, we'd simply use the relation $a=r\sin\alpha$ to determine either $a$ or $\alpha$, whichever you consider to be flexible.) Please edit your question to include *exactly* which properties you want to control. (Can you show the "geometrical definition" you mention? I've never heard of "flank angle".) Comments —especially comments on answers— are easily overlooked, so anything that affects the nature of a problem should be stated in the question itself.

Comment: dear blue ! I had not received notification from your new update ! what an amazing answer !!! thank you !!! I was also thinking, that I should be able to make the shape of the circles a function of the pitch : which is the distance between the centers of  2 neighbouring circles. so the circles remain tangent while this pitch is changing and alfa changes to keep the circles tangent. is this also possible to define as a function ?

Comment: to add the second paramter to the previous one : and : the height of the circle , which means the distance from the tip of top circles to the tip of bottom circle

 also , the diameters of the top circles are r1 and the diameters of bottom ones are r2 : r2 >r1